# Not able to connect to postgres on aws ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

When I run python3 manage.py makemigrations.

It throws the following error.
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

So I had checked whether postgres is working fine

I had tried sudo su - postgres
It went inside the postgres cmd prompt so it became
postgres@ip-10-254-3-58:~$

now when I try psql  I get the same error as when I run python3 manage.py makemigrations.

postgres@ip-10-254-3-58:~$psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Please help me in fixing this issue.

TIA

Kind Regards,

Bharath AK